# How to update the JSON field

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to update the particular field in the JSON response, however i am able to parse through the JSON, but i am unable to update the field values.

Parsed through the JSON response and tried using

`Operands_parse.SelectToken("FieldValue").Replace("1234,5678");`

But when replace is changing the format of the response which is not suppose to happen

`JObject Operands_parse = (JObject)Operands[0];
    Operands_parse.SelectToken("FieldValue").Replace("1234,5678");`

Below is the JSON snippet:

```
  "Predicate": {
    "Field": null,
    "FieldValue": null,
    "FilterOperator": "Equals",
    "Operands": [
      {
        "Field": {
          "Name": "Participant.IsPrimary",
          "Alias": "Participant Is Primary",
          "ValueInput": "UserName",
          "FieldType": "Boolean",
          "SortProxyName": "IsPrimary",
          "PrismFieldName": "IsPrimaryFA",
          "PrismDisplayFieldName": null,
          "FieldValue": null,
          "IsCustom": false,
          "DependentField": null,
          "Disabled": false,
          "PlannedForDeprecation": false
        },
        "FieldValue": [
          "true"
        ]
```

Output:

```
"FieldValue":
      "1234,
       5678",
```

Expected:

```
 "FieldValue": [
      "1234",
      "5678"
    ],
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant JSON snippet?

Comment: I would suggest to modify the object's properties which you want to modify and then serialize the objects to Json string again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things got worked after converting the speicfic field to the JArray from which i can upadte the values.

```
  string[] CRs ;
  CRs = new string[2] {"1234","5678"};  

  JObject Operands_parse = (JObject)Operands[0];
  JToken FieldValue_t;
  Operands_parse.TryGetValue("FieldValue", out FieldValue_t);

    JArray item = (JArray)FieldValue_t;
/*Removed old values*/
    item.RemoveAt(0);
    item.RemoveAt(1);
/*Added New Values*/
    item.Add(items_no[0]);
    item.Add(items_no[1]);
```

`

> ```
>   "Predicate": {
>     "Field": null,
>     "FieldValue": null,
>     "FilterOperator": "Equals",
>     "Operands": [
>       {
>         "Field": {
>           "Name": "ChangeRequestParticipant.IsPrimary",
>           "Alias": "Participant Is Primary",
>           "ValueInput": "UserName",
>           "FieldType": "Boolean",
>           "SortProxyName": "ChangeRequestParticipant.IsPrimary",
>           "PrismFieldName": "IsPrimaryFA",
>           "PrismDisplayFieldName": null,
>           "FieldValue": null,
>           "IsCustom": false,
>           "DependentField": null,
>           "Disabled": false,
>           "PlannedForDeprecation": false
>         },
>         "FieldValue": [
>           "1234",
>           "5678"
>         ],`
> ```

[Took reference from this link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm)